# Trouble referring to HTML document inside an iframe

Tags: excel, vba, recaptcha

I'm having some trouble trying to refer to elements inside the iframe containing a recaptcha.

My script's goal is to help a human filling a search form, clicking "Search", direct the user to deal with the reCaptcha (I'm not trying to break the captcha, or anything like that) and, after the search, open the found page to get some information and show it to the user to confirm.

The problem is, when I programmatically click Search button, reCaptcha script will act. Sometimes it will clear access and identify the request is being made by a human (when the user were doing other stuff just before using the script); other times it will present the reCaptcha popup with images testing if you are human.

I need to distinguish when reCaptcha script identifies automatically or presents the captcha images, because in the latter cases I'll show a popup telling the user to go deal with the captcha.

Here is the problem: I can identify the reCaptcha iframe (held in the variable `ifrCaptcha`); I also know when the challenge is shown by the visibility CSS style of the `div` containing the iframe (`ifrCaptcha.parentElement.parentElement.Style.visibility`). But I haven't managed to get a way refering to the document contained in the iframe.

When I use `ifrCaptcha.document` it gets the main document of the page--not the iframe document.

How can I refer to the iframe document?

The page is not public, but I think any page with reCaptcha would do the job; the code is as follows (the objetive is only to refer to anything in the iframe document; e.g., the title of the iframe document):

```
Sub AbrePesquisa()

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer , DocHTML As HTMLDocument, ifrDocHTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim intCont As Integer
    Dim ifrCaptcha As HTMLIFrame
    Dim bolCaptchaValidado As Boolean, bolCaptchaVisivel As Boolean


    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    IE.Navigate "http://www.whatever-url-which-uses-recaptcha.com"

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop  Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set DocHTML = IE.document

    Set ifrCaptcha = Nothing
    Set ifrCaptcha = PegarCaptcha(DocHTML)
    strSrcCaptcha = ifrCaptcha.src ' When page reloads, the iframe src changes a bit, so I need it

    DocHTML.getElementById("SearchString").Value = strSearchParameters
    DocHTML.getElementById("SearchButton").Click

    ' Wait for browser to process the reCaptcha script
    Do
        Set ifrCaptcha = Nothing
        Set ifrCaptcha = PegarCaptcha(DocHTML)

        bolCaptchaVisivel = ExibindoCaptcha(DocHTML, ifrCaptcha)

        If bolCaptchaVisivel = False Then
            If strSrcCaptcha <> ifrCaptcha.src Then bolCaptchaValidado = True
        End If

    Loop Until bolCaptchaValidado = True Or bolCaptchaVisivel = True

    Set ifrDocHTML = ifrCaptcha.document

    Debug.Print ifrDocHTML.Title ' Returns the main page title
    Debug.Print ifrDocHTML.InnerHtml ' Returns the main page HTML

End Sub

Function ExibindoCaptcha(DocHTML As HTMLDocument, ifrCaptcha As HTMLIFrame) As Boolean

    If ifrCaptcha Is Nothing Then
        ExibindoCaptcha = False

    ElseIf ifrCaptcha.parentElement Is Nothing Then ' The page I'm working in has the captcha inside a div nested in another div, both of which VBA returns as non-existing when reCaptcha isn't showing (even I seeing both exists in browser, in Inspector mode)
        ExibindoCaptcha = False

    ElseIf ifrCaptcha.parentElement.parentElement Is Nothing Then
        ExibindoCaptcha = False

    Else
        If ifrCaptcha.parentElement.parentElement.Style.visibility = "visible" Then
            ExibindoCaptcha = True
        Else
            ExibindoCaptcha = False
        End If
    End If

End Function

Function PegarCaptcha(DocHTML As HTMLDocument) As HTMLIFrame

    Dim ifrCont As HTMLIFrame

    For Each ifrCont In DocHTML.getElementsByTagName("iframe")
        If ifrCont.Title = "desafio reCAPTCHA" Then Exit For
    Next ifrCont

    If ifrCont Is Nothing Then
        Set PegarCaptcha = Nothing

    Else
        Set PegarCaptcha = ifrCont

    End If

End Function
```

Somebody outta there can help me refer to the document contained in the Captcha iframe?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Arent Captchas supposed to be there to prevent people from automating those things? and you are asking how to automate them? or am i missing something?

Comment: Not exactly, for three reasons. Firstly, my application doesn't make preemptive, excessive nor autonomous requests--it doesn't automate the use, only helps a human user the boring part of filling the blanks in the forms. Secondly, it doesn't make requests directly to the server. On the contrary, it opens the browser and emulates the operation made by the human user alone. Thirdly (and in conclusion), because of the reasons above, it doesn't overload the server. (continue...)

Comment: (...continuance). It's more like the opposite: these information will have to be gathered and registered anyway, activity usually made by human users by hand. Humans doing it without help of a machine eventually commit mistakes, which could lead to posterior failures and to new accesses to the same websites in order to correct these mistypings. I'm in close contact with the systems administrators; they are aware of my activities and it doesn't bother them, because of these reasons. The captcha is there to prevent people who make excessive requests (my application only does the necessary ones).

Comment: To finish, the system administrator's don't worry for me scraping my data the way I do, but they also aren't willing to develop any API or other way for scrapping the data without the captcha. The data will be scrapped anyway (and this is why the system is there)--this can be done by human hands alone, leading to mistakes, mistypings, etc, or by human hands overwatching AIs, which I think is better and less inclined to result in errors. To make it short: I'm not trying to break a system; the captcha is not there to prevent the use I make, but I'm collaterally affected.